# Get rootNode of node

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

In an ARKit project, when the user taps the screen, I want to get the `rootNode` of the element, that the user want to interact with.

## Gesture & Hit test

```
func screenTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let hitTestResult = sceneView.hitTest(touchLocation)
    if let result = hitTestResult.first {
        guard let rootNode = getRoot(for: result.node) else {return}
        ...
    }
```

## Recursive function to get the root node

```
func getRoot(for node: SCNNode) -> SCNNode? {
    if let node = node.parent {
        return getRoot(for: node)
    }
    else {
        return node
    }
}
```

But it seems odd to me that Swift doesn't offer something by default, while offering recursive methods for child nodes.

- Is there an alternative/better approach to this?
- Should I write this function as extension for `SCNNode`?

Comment: Any new solutions? Do you use your code?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it equivalent to `sceneView.scene.rootNode`?

Comment: Hm, yeah you are right. But that is not what I'm trying to archive. What I need is the root of the model that was detected/hit by that ray trace. `hitTestResult.first` returns the exact node that was hit.